# R returning the value as "Error in qr(.swts * gr) : dims [product 63] do not match the length of object [111]"

Tags: r

I'm new to R. I need to do Bass Prediction using this code, but R gives me these errors:

"Error in qr(.swts * gr) :
dims [product 63] do not match the length of object [111]
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In lhs - rhs :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In .swts * gr :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

The script is as such:

```
library(DIMORA)
library(diffusion)
library(netdiffuseR)

data <- read.csv("Dataset02.csv")

m <- dim(data)[1] - 20
result <- matrix(nrow=m, ncol=7)

for (i in 21:dim(data)[1]) {

#############################
# Initialization of variables
#############################

   temp <- matrix(nrow=6, ncol=5)

   # Dimora
   bass1a <- BASS.standard(sales = data$defect[1:i], method = 'nls', prelimestimates = c(sum(data$defect[1:i])+100, 0.01, 0.01),
            ous= 100, alpha = 0.05, display = F, max.iter = 1000)

   m1a <- bass1a$Estimate[1, 1]
   p1a <- bass1a$Estimate[2, 1]
   q1a <- bass1a$Estimate[3, 1]
   mse_bass1a <- sqrt(mean((bass1a$fitted - bass1a$data)^2))
   b_Rsquare1a <- bass1a$Rsquared
   temp[1, ] <- c(m1a, p1a, q1a, mse_bass1a, b_Rsquare1a)

   # diffusion
   T <- data$week[1:i]
   S_hat <- mean(data$defect[1:i])
   TSS <- sum((data$defect[1:i] - S_hat)^2)


   bass2a <- diffusion(data$defect[1:i], cumulative = FALSE, type = "bass", optim = "nm")

   m2a <- bass2a$w[3]
   p2a <- bass2a$w[1]
   q2a <- bass2a$w[2]
   ngete2a <- exp(-(p2a + q2a) * T)
   bass_pdf2a <- m2a * (p2a * (p2a + q2a)^2 * ngete2a)/((p2a + q2a * ngete2a)^2)
   mse_bass2a <- sqrt(mean((data$defect[1:i] - bass_pdf2a)^2))
   b_RSS2a <- sum((data$defect[1:i] - bass_pdf2a)^2)
   b_Rsquare2a <- (1 - b_RSS2a/TSS)
   temp[2, ] <- c(m2a, p2a, q2a, mse_bass2a, b_Rsquare2a)


   bass2b <- diffusion(data$defect[1:i], cumulative = TRUE, type = "bass", optim = "nm")

   m2b <- bass2b$w[3]
   p2b <- bass2b$w[1]
   q2b <- bass2b$w[2]
   ngete2b <- exp(-(p2b + q2b) * T)
   bass_pdf2b <- m2b * (p2b * (p2b + q2b)^2 * ngete2b)/((p2b + q2b * ngete2b)^2)
   mse_bass2b <- sqrt(mean((data$defect[1:i] - bass_pdf2b)^2))
   b_RSS2b <- sum((data$defect[1:i] - bass_pdf2b)^2)
   b_Rsquare2b <- (1 - b_RSS2b/TSS)
   temp[3, ] <- c(m2b, p2b, q2b, mse_bass2b, b_Rsquare2b)


   bass2c <- diffusion(data$defect[1:i], cumulative = FALSE, type = "bass", optim = "hj")

   m2c <- bass2c$w[3]
   p2c <- bass2c$w[1]
   q2c <- bass2c$w[2]

   input <- data[1:i, ]
   m0 <- sum(data$defect[1:i])

   bass2c <- NULL

   tryCatch({
   bass2c <- nls(defect ~ m *(((p+q)^2/p)*exp(-(p+q)*day))/(1+(q/p)*exp(-(p+q)*day))^2, data = input, start=c(list(m=m0, p = 0.01, q = 0.01)), lower = c(m0, 0, 0), algorithm = "port")
   }, error=function(e){})

   if (!is.null(bass2c$p)) {
      m2c <- coef(bass2c)[1]
      p2c <- coef(bass2c)[2]
      q2c <- coef(bass2c)[3]
   } else {
      p2c <- mean(c(p2a, p2b))
      q2c <- mean(c(q2a, q2b))
      m2c <- 1.96*m0
   }

   ngete2c <- exp(-(p2c + q2c) * T)
   bass_pdf2c <- m2c * (p2c * (p2c + q2c)^2 * ngete2c)/((p2c + q2c * ngete2c)^2)
   mse_bass2c <- sqrt(mean((data$defect[1:i] - bass_pdf2c)^2))
   b_RSS2c <- sum((data$defect[1:i] - bass_pdf2c)^2)
   b_Rsquare2c <- (1 - b_RSS2c/TSS)
   temp[4, ] <- c(m2c, p2c, q2c, mse_bass2c, b_Rsquare2c)


   bass2d <- diffusion(data$defect[1:i], cumulative = TRUE, type = "bass", optim = "nm")

   m2d <- bass2d$w[3]
   p2d <- bass2d$w[1]
   q2d <- bass2d$w[2]

   bass2d <- nls(cum_defect ~ m * (1 - exp(-(p+q)*day))/(1 + q * exp(-(p + q)*day)/p), data = input, start=c(list(m=m0, p = 0.001, q = 0.001)), lower = c(m0, 0, 0), algorithm = "port")

   m2d <- coef(bass2d)[1]
   p2d <- coef(bass2d)[2]
   q2d <- coef(bass2d)[3]

   ngete2d <- exp(-(p2d + q2d) * T)
   bass_pdf2d <- m2d * (p2d * (p2d + q2d)^2 * ngete2d)/((p2d + q2d * ngete2d)^2)
   mse_bass2d <- sqrt(mean((data$defect[1:i] - bass_pdf2d)^2))
   b_RSS2d <- sum((data$defect[1:i] - bass_pdf2d)^2)
   b_Rsquare2d <- (1 - b_RSS2d/TSS)

   temp[5, ] <- c(m2d, p2d, q2d, mse_bass2d, b_Rsquare2d)
   temp[5, ] <- c(0, 0, 0, 999999, 0)

   #######################################################
   # Calculating Bass model using "netdiffuseR" package &
   # We use grid from 1.10 - 3 by 0.1 for normalization factor m
   #######################################################
   d <- 1
   b_equation <- matrix(nrow=20, ncol=5)

   for (n in seq(from=1.05, to=3, by=0.1)) {
      bass_nls3 <- NULL
      m_Yt <- sum(data$defect[1:i])

      tryCatch({
      bass_nls3 <- fitbass(data$cum_defect/(n*m_Yt))
      }, error=function(e){})

      if (!is.null(bass_nls3$p)) {
         p3 <- bass_nls3$p
         q3 <- bass_nls3$q
         m3 <- n*m_Yt
       } else {
         p3 <- mean(c(p2a, p2b))
         q3 <- mean(c(q2a, q2b))
         m3 <- n*m_Yt
      }

   ngete3 <- exp(-(p3 + q3) * T)
   bass_pdf3 <- m3 * (p3 * (p3 + q3)^2 * ngete3)/((p3 + q3 * ngete3)^2)
   mse_bass3 <- sqrt(mean((data$defect[1:i] - bass_pdf3)^2))
   b_RSS3 <- sum((data$defect[1:i] - bass_pdf3)^2)
   b_Rsquare3 <- (1 - b_RSS3/TSS)

   b_equation[d, 1] <- m3
   b_equation[d, 2] <- p3
   b_equation[d, 3] <- q3
   b_equation[d, 4] <- mse_bass3
   b_equation[d, 5] <- b_Rsquare3
   d <- d + 1
   }

   b1 <- min(b_equation[ , 4])
   b2 <- which.min(b_equation[ , 4])

   temp[6, ] <- b_equation[b2, ]

   for (j in 1:6) {
      if ((temp[j, 1] > sum(data$defect[1:i]) * (dim(data)[1]/i) * 1.96) | (temp[j, 1] < sum(data$defect[1:i]))) {
         temp[ j, 4] <- 99999999
      }
   }

   k1 <- min(temp[ , 4])
   k2 <- which.min(temp[ , 4])

   result[i-20, 1] <- sum(data$defect[1:i])
   result[i-20, 2] <- temp[k2, 1]
   result[i-20, 3] <- temp[k2, 2]
   result[i-20, 4] <- temp[k2, 3]
   result[i-20, 5] <- temp[k2, 4]
   result[i-20, 6] <- temp[k2, 5]
   result[i-20, 7] <- k2

}
```

My dataset is in this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-XF9iU48Zj5wX8hABBQ7FwbXxjhuANnA/view?usp=sharing. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include your data, or a subset of it, using `dput(data)`. Also, it would be helpful if you narrowed down your code to only the problem, instead of including your whole script. Read more about how to create a minimal repex here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).